# OpenCV cv::Mat element access

Tags: c++, opencv, матрицы

```
cv::Mat matrix= cv::Mat::zeros(3,4,CV_8U);

matrix.at<float>(0,0)=1;
matrix.at<float>(0,1)=2;
matrix.at<float>(0,2)=3;

matrix.at<float>(1,0)=4;
matrix.at<float>(1,1)=5;
matrix.at<float>(1,2)=6;

matrix.at<float>(2,0)=7;
matrix.at<float>(2,1)=8;
matrix.at<float>(2,2)=9;

for (int i=0;i<matrix.rows;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<matrix.cols;j++){
        float temp= matrix.at<float>(i,j);
        std::cout<<temp;
        std::cout<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Excpected output:

1230

4560

7890

Current output:

1478

4789

7890

Что не так?

Comment: `Current output` в любом случае не соответствует коду в примере, т.к. в примере выводится пробел после каждого значения. Вероятно, вам нужно пересобрать проект, либо вы вводите нас в заблуждение.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because of memory allocation.
float type and CV_8U are not the same. When at the step of matrix creation and element access defined the same format everything works .

For example:

```
     cv::Mat matrix = cv::Mat_<std::complex<double> >(3, 4);

     matrix.at<double>(0,0)=1;
```

provides same data type